# Que es o porque ocurre Thread Exit en Delphi y no se inicia la aplicacion

Tags: delphi

Mi aplicacion no se inicia y cuando compilo con **F9** obtengo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como veran dice **Exit**, entiendo que termina el proceso del programa. ¿Alguien sabe por que aparece ese mensaje o que debería hacer?

Agrego: En el Administrador de Tareas de windows sigue apareciendo el proceso.

Este es el codigo del evento Create de mi Formulario el cual se atasca antes del Run:

```pascal
     procedure TPEDIDO.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
     var
      idpedido, intUltimo: integer;

     begin


      Position := poScreenCenter;
      // obtengo el pedido actual
      DataModule1.cdstablaped.Open;
      intUltimo := DataModule1.cdstablaped.RecordCount;
      DBEdit1.Text := inttostr(intUltimo);
      if DBEdit1.Text <> '' then
      begin
        idpedido := StrToInt(DBEdit1.Text);
        DataModule1.cdspedidos.Close;
        DataModule1.cdsdetpedido.Close;
        DataModule1.cdspedidos.FetchParams;
        DataModule1.cdsdetpedido.FetchParams;
        DataModule1.cdscliactual.Close;
        DataModule1.cdscliactual.FetchParams;

        DataModule1.cdspedidos.Params.ParamByName('idp').Value := idpedido;
        DataModule1.cdspedidos.Open;
        MaskEdit1.Text := DataModule1.cdspedidosFecha.AsString;
        MaskEdit2.Text := DataModule1.cdspedidosVencimiento.AsString;
        DataModule1.cdscliactual.Params.ParamByName('idc').Value :=
        DataModule1.cdspedidosIdCliente.AsInteger;
        DataModule1.cdsdetpedido.Params.ParamByName('idp').Value := idpedido;
        DataModule1.cdscliactual.Open;
        DataModule1.cdsdetpedido.Open;

     end;

       DataModule1.cdsproductos.First;

        begin
         PEDIDO.gpedidotemp.Columns[2].PickList.Add
            (DataModule1.cdsproductosCodigo.AsString);

         PEDIDO.gpedidotemp.Columns[3].PickList.Add
          (DataModule1.cdslistasNombre.AsString);

         DataModule1.cdsproductos.Next;
      end;

     end;
```

Queda iterando en el ultimo bloque, aparentemente esta bien pero quizas yo no le di suficiente tiempo. ¿Me convendria utilizar el evento OnShow?

Comment: El mensaje `Thread exit` es normal que aparezca en la consola cuando terminan hilos y no parece ser la causa de que tu aplicación salga antes de tiempo.  Probablemente se está produciendo una excepción antes de llegar a ejecutr la línea `Aplication.Run` de tu `dpr`. En la configuración default, si ejecutas la aplicación con el depurador integrado, el IDE se detiene al haber una excepción.

Comment: Gracias @jachguate por tu ayuda diaria en todos mis temas! Te comento que el problema ocurre antes de la instrucción Run, concretamente antes de un formulario que tengo. Asi que decidi colocar nuevamente un breakpoint en la unidad dicho formulario. Ahora edito la pregunta y agrego el codigo. Sos un genio

Comment: La _solución_ más utilizada si tienes rutinas de inicialización que son tardadas es agregar un _splash screen_, que no es más que un formulario simple, usualmente con una imagen y algún label, que muestra el progreso de la _inicialización_ del programa (ves una cada vez que entras a Delphi). De esta forma, no tienes que cambiar lo que ya programaste, el usuario, de cualquier manera, tiene que esperar el tiempo que tarde en inicializar el programa.